# Class file not being read

Tags: java, ubuntu, command-line

When I compile a java file, it gets compiled and I am able to see the class file in the same location. But when I try to run it using the java command, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UDPServer (wrong name: com/prasanna/udp/UDPServer)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:787)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:447)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

How should I correct this error? How should I make the java program know the path of this class file?

PS: I am very new to command line execution of a Java file.

Comment: Is this directly from the command line, or this class being referenced from another class?

Comment: @ChrisChambers I type "java UDPServer" directly from the command line. UDPServer.java is my java file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the class is in the package `com.prasanna.udp` and is named `UDPServer`. Assuming the `com/prasanna/udp` directory tree, containing the .class files, is located in `/home/Prasanna/java/classes`, the command line should be:

```
java -cp /home/Prasanna/java/classes com.prasanna.udp.UDPServer
```

If your class depends on a jar file located in `/foo/bar/somelib.jar`, iy should also be placed in the classpath:

```
java -cp /home/Prasanna/java/classes:/foo/bar/somelib.jar com.prasanna.udp.UDPServer
```